# static mouse wont active hover on spinning cube (relative face)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed an online tutorial (https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/cube) to make a spinning 3d cube. I added a CSS animation to make the cube spin and show all of its faces.

```
@keyframes cubeSpin {
    0% { transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);}
    17% {transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(0);}
    34% {transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(90deg);}
    50% {transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);}
    67% {transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateZ(90deg);}
    84% {transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);} 
}
```

Currently, if you check out my codepen (https://codepen.io/durandamien1997/pen/rNymxMo) you will notice, if you hover over the cube, it will change the face colors of the cube.

```
.cube__face:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

However, you will also notice that if you don't move your mouse around and let it sit static over the cube, when the new face of the cube enters the vicinity of your mouse, the :hover on that face will not be activated, but :hover effects will stick to the initial face, or the last face the last time you moved your mouse.

I have tried using z-index to set each face on it's own layer that way :hover will active for each of them automatically, but that only made it so :hover is activated when the highest indexed face hits the mouse.

```
/* z-index attempt */
.cube.show-front  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(   0deg); z-index: 1 }
.cube.show-right  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY( -90deg); z-index: 2 }
.cube.show-back   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 3 }
.cube.show-left   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(  90deg); z-index: 4 }
.cube.show-top    { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX( -90deg); z-index: 5 }
.cube.show-bottom { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  90deg); z-index: 6 }
```

How do I make :hover activate without having to move the mouse when current face is in view?